# What is the return value of &"suchString"?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-address, c-strings

The output of this snippet of code:

```
char* str1 = "suchString";
printf("%s %s\n", &"suchString", &str1);
```

is:

> suchString �WO:+(or any unknown symbols)

What is the difference and why the output not the same?

**EDIT**
If you trying to eliminate the & operator as follows:

```
char* str1 = "suchString";
printf("%s %s\n", "suchString", &str1);
```

The output is the same of the first snippet of code.
Now, is how the "suchString" is the same of &"suchString"?

Comment: Why are you supplying `char**`, the address of the pointer, as an argument to a `%s` placeholder? I'm honestly surprised the first argument even worked.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](htttp://gcc.gnu.org/) . You would get a warning

Comment: this is a quiz but i can't know why &"suchString" don't print an address such as &str1

Comment: Because string literals are arrays, not pointers.

Comment: @tadman: The code does not provide an argument of type `char**`. The expression `&"suchString"` is of  type `char(*)[11]`, a pointer to an array of 11 `char`s.\

Comment: @KeithThompson In the second case it does. In the first, yeah, I can see what you mean.

Comment: @tadman: You're right, I didn't read closely enough. The three arguments in the `printf` call, including the format string, are of types `char*` (after array-to-pointer decay), `char(*)[11]`, and `char**`. The second and third arguments both need to be of type `char*`.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's an important distinction between directly calling `&` on an inline string where the character array properties are preserved and `&` on a variable defined with the same thing where that information is lost, so that explains why the first one, astonishingly, works. I've never been mad-scientist enough to call `&` on an inline string because I'm not even sure why you'd ever want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* str1 = "suchString";
printf("%s %s\n", &"suchString", &str1);
```

The `%s` specifier requires an argument of type `char*`, which must be a pointer to a string. You've provided arguments of types `char (*)[11]` and `char**`. Your code has undefined behavior, which means that in principle it could do literally anything.

A string literal is an array. The address of an array refers to the same memory location as the address of the array's first element, but it's of a different type. Passing just `"suchString"` as the second argument would be correct, since the array "decays" to a pointer to its first element.

In an implementation where all pointers have the same representation (which is typical but not required), passing a pointer to the same memory location but with the wrong type is likely to "work". `printf` is special in that it can accept arguments of different types, so the compiler can't necessarily diagnose type errors. For a non-variadic function, an error like this would probably be rejected at compile time.

`str1` is a pointer, not an array. You've initialized it to point to the initial character of the string literal. You could pass `str1` to `printf`, but `&str1` is the address of a pointer object, which is not only of the wrong type, but doesn't point to a string at all. Thus the output is garbage.

If you want to print the string values, you can do this:

```
const char* str1 = "suchString";
printf("%s %s\n", "suchString", str1);
```

(I've added `const` so the compiler will complain if you try to modify the contents of the string literal.)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
&"suchString"
```

takes the address of a string literal. String literals are *arrays*, not pointers.

Had you compiled with warnings enabled, you had knew already:

```
prog.c:5:14: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[11]' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s %s\n", &"suchString", &str1);
             ~^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.c:5:17: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char **' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s %s\n", &"suchString", &str1);
                ~^                    ~~~~~
```

The first is of type `char (*)[11]`, while the second is of type `char **`.

As for the garbage values, you are providing an address of a pointer to `%s` format, thus ruining the print. If you used `%p` instead, you would see an address being printed out, e.g. "0x7ffe676f5588".

Same goes for when attempting to print the address of the string literal, with the string specifier in `printf()`.

Moreover, you should cast to `void*`, like this:

```
printf("%p %p\n", (void*)"suchString", (void*)str1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried to eliminate the & operator and it is the same &"suchString" = "suchString".. why?

Comment: @AhmedYasen: You said "it is the same". What is the same as what?

Comment: The `%p` specifier requires an argument of type `void*`. If you want to print the valuue of a pointer of a different type, you should cast it. (You can probably get away without the cast in most implementations, but it's good practice.)

Comment: @AhmedYasen, in C, a referenced to an array name degrades to the address of the array.  Note: this statement: `&"suchString"` is actually wrong because it is trying to get the address of an address.  Thankfully, C properly returns the proper (address) value